Upper and lower bound rules of polynomial functions that have a negative leading coefficient
Thanks for the help provided in my previous question but I still need more the definition for upper and lower bound rule is as following:
Upper and Lower Bound Rules
Let f(x) be a polynomial with real coefficients and a positive leading coefficient. Divide f(x) by x-c using synthetic division.

If c > 0 and each number in the last row is either positive or zero, then c is an upper bound for the real zeros of f
If c < 0 and the numbers in the last row are alternately positive and negative (zero entries count as positive or negative), then c is a lower bound for the real zeros of f.

I was wondering what would happened if the leading coefficient is negative and why can't we do that? thanks and sorry for the disturbance
secondly in number 1 do we consider 0 as positive or negative or we can choose or neither?

Try it and see.

The roots if $f(x)$ and $-f(x)$ are the same, so if the leading coefficient is negative, multiply the polynomial by $-1$.

But as $-(a_n)x^n + ....  = -(a_n x^n +.....)$ then $c$ is an upper bound to the zeros of $f$ if and only if $-c$ is a lower bound to the zeros of $-f$.

thanks all for the answers

please publish them in the official answer section

so I can accept them
